# Proving that $f$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiplicative-function

Let's consider the following function:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} (x^2+y^2)\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right) & \text{if }x^2+y^2\not=0 \\{}\\ 0 & \text{if }x=y=0  \end{cases}$$

I know that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $0$. How to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Is that $\;-1\;$ on the sine's argument or on the sine itself?

Comment: @Timbuc Why is the extra space necessary?\

Comment: @dragon Doesn't it look nicer and neater?

Comment: I assume the exponent is on the argument of the sine function.  Correct?

Comment: Does the $^{-1}$ belong to sin as a whole or just the argument

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Change to polar coordinates and show

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2\sin(r^{-2})-0}{r}=0$$

Hint 2:  The sine function is bounded.